# How to create Master/Detail in the Material Design World

Tags: java, android, xml, material-design, master-detail

How can elevation be added to the detail pane of a Master/Detail view to give a shadow underneath it alongside being positioned to partially cover the toolbar (like the bottom image below)? I tried using `android:elevation="4dp"` but that didn't work for me.

**XML layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_singleline"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:showDividers="middle">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/master_container"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_container"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**current boring result**
[image]

**expected result**
[image]

**item under master toolbar**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/master_container"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/divider"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/masterToolbar" />
```

Comment: Use `app:elevation="4dp"` then try. However, using `stateListAnimator` seems to be the best approach nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a somewhat complex layout, especially given the search action bar icon aligned with the rightmost edge of the "master" column.

I suspect this is functionally a `FrameLayout` (or subclass) holding a horizontal `LinearLayout` with the "detail" pane as a `CardView` (with 0dp corner radius) overlaid on the rest of the content. Here's a quick template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/masterToolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/detailBackgroundToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/detailBackgroundToolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:background="?colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/masterToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/masterToolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/masterToolbar" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#eee"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailBackgroundToolbar" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/divider"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/detailToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:background="#ccc"
                app:title="Detail title" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:padding="16dp"
                android:text="@string/lorem_medium"
                android:textColor="#1b1b1b"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

The only real trick here is the fake "detailBackgroundToolbar" toolbar that exists only to space the master toolbar correctly (the master toolbar needs to end in the middle of the screen so that the action icons are in the right place).

Comment: Where's the view for the white recentagle underneath the main toolbar? I think you forgot to include that in your XML suggestion.

Comment: Right now there's no view there. You can put whatever you want below the toolbar and to the start of the divider.

Comment: Cool. I'm tried to add an item under the master toolbar, but for some reason it overlaps the master toolbar rather than starting from the bottom of it. Positioning to the start of the divier works perfectly. Do you know what's wrong with my constraints? (see **item under master toolbar**)

Comment: Try changing the height to `0dp` and let me know if that fixes it. I also think the weight attribute is irrelevant here.

Comment: Please update your code to include the Toolbar icon on the right. I've tried implementing that but it doesn't work for me at the moment.

Comment: I just called `setSupportActionBar()` on `masterToolbar` and then overrode `onCreateOptionsMenu()` as normal. That's a single-item menu with `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"`

Comment: For some reason, the Options Menu appears on the larger screen but not on the smaller screens.

Comment: Hm, don't know why that would be. Maybe there's just not enough width in the toolbar for everything if the screen is too small? Could always switch to a single-pane layout for those smaller screens.

Comment: There's plenty of space. This definietly deserves another question. If you have a look at the following question, you'll see what I mean: [Question - Overflow menu vanished on Toolbar despite setting properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53016407/overflow-menu-vanished-on-toolbar-despite-setting-properties)